# Attached image not showing on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, activerecord, erb

I have a "short" model as follows:

```
class Short < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :director
  belongs_to :composer
  has_one_attached :clip
  has_one_attached :thumbnail
end
```

And I'm seeding:

```
curta1 = Short.new()
curta1.name = "FortePiano"
curta1.launch = Date.today()
curta1.datasheet = "Eu sou um curta!"
curta1.director = director1
curta1.composer = composer1

curta1.save
curta1.thumbnail.attach(io:File.open(Rails.root + "app/assets/images/download.jpeg"), filename: 'download.jpeg')
```

However, when I try to display the thumbnail in the view like this:

```
<% @shorts.each do |short| %>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <%= main_app.url_for(short.thumbnail) %>
    <%= link_to (short.name + " - " + short.launch.strftime("%Y")), short %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I get this error:
`` undefined method `attachment_url' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::RoutesProxy:0x00007f90e68c0e00> ``

I've tested running `short.thumbnail.attached?` and it returns `true`

Can anybody help me to propperly show the thumbnail?

Using Rails 6.1.3.2

PS: if I use

```
<%= image_tag(short.thumbnail) %>
```

it returns me `` Can't resolve image into URL: undefined method `attachment_url' for #<ActionView::Base:0x007f90e689e7b0> ``

Comment: What does it returns when you do this?
`curta1.thumbnail.attached?`

Comment: It returns me "true"

Comment: Try this `image_tag(url_for(short.thumbnail))`

Comment: This returns me `undefined method 'attachment_path' for #<ActionView::Base:0x007f7511236008>`. I tried putting `image_tag(main_app.url_for(short.thumbnail))` too, however this returned me: `undefined method 'attachment_url' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::RoutesProxy:0x00007f7510ab51d0>`

Comment: @brenovisk7 is this a private app ?
Do you have minimal setup to re-produce like public git repo?

Comment: It is not private, here is its link app in github: https://github.com/BrenoSCabral/fest_sol_maior